# Google Analytics code wont load on updated html

Tags: html, analytics

I am working on a website that was mirrored from the parent company's main site. When I try adding google analytics, the page updated pages do not contain the code.

Comment: can you show us the page ? and give us more precision on how you added the code ?

Comment: This page https://www.newmatic.co.ke/products/washing.html. I keep editing it and adding the tracking code but the live version doesn't reflect the same

Comment: am sure there is a cache system behind this ? if you rename the file to something else and call the this file ? if you are able to see the code in the new file it means that there is cache

Comment: when I rename the file and call it the page doesnt show at all

Comment: no, you don't need to call the same page ... rename it to washing-1.html and call washing-1.html not washing.html

Comment: this now looks like something else newmatic.co.ke/products/washing-1.html. the same page saved doesnt show anything

Comment: any file that i rename takes on the same shape